# How to specify seconds in the shutdown command line tool?

Tags: macos, command-line, shutdown

With the cmd `shutdown -h +<time>`you can only specify minutes for time.

I tried using decimals but it just shuts down immediately.

#### Background

If you shutdown from terminal then the terminal stays open when you power on and can take a while to be usable.

I hardly touch the GUI no way I'm going to scroll all the way over to the button.

I got around this by putting this in my `~/bash_profile`:

```bash
alias sd='sudo shutdown -h +1 && exit'
```

This shuts down after a minute, giving the terminal time to exit. Or I should say writing the cmd in this way means it gives an exit code.

Only problem is I want it to shutdown in 10 or less seconds but there seems to be no way to specify seconds.

#### Update:

```bash
shutdown -h now && exit
shutdown -h now; exit
shutdown -h now; anycmd
```

`shutdown -h now; anycmd`

**Will never reach the next cmd as it occurs in the foreground, once it completes the computer is off.**

`shutdown -h +1 && exit`

**Confused me, it was nothing to do with the time delay, it was because the cmd occurs in the background so the exit is reached.**

So you have to run the cmd in the background so that the exit can be reached.

I got the answer first after realising this:

```bash
alias sd='shutdown -h now & exit
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it with this:

```bash
alias sd='sudo shutdown -h now & exit'
```

This stops the cmd from holding up the terminal as it goes to background so the exit is reached and the terminal closes.

#### Update

This cmd is unreliable, although the terminal closes, sometimes on power on the terminal will be open so now I do:

```bash
alias caff='caffeinate -dimsu'
alias sd='caff & sudo shutdown -h +1; exit'
```

Then close the lid.

`caffeinate &` is necessary as when the lid is closed the computer locks so will never shutdown.

Comment: unjustified downvote. Highest voted answer has the same cmd which was written later has an unneeded `no hip` and is buggy. Clearly a personal issue with this obnoxious user. Problem is unsolvable, so this is the next best solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
alias sd='sleep 10; nohup shutdown -h now & exit'
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146870/discussion-on-answer-by-nohillside-how-to-specify-seconds-in-the-shutdown-comman); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't specify seconds.

From the `shutdown` man page:

> **time**    Time is the time at which shutdown will bring the system down and may be the
> word *now* (indicating an immediate shutdown) or specify a future time in one of
> two formats: +number, or yymmddhhmm, where the year, month, and day may be
> defaulted to the current system values.  The first form brings the system down
> in number minutes and the second at the absolute time specified.

However you mentioned that you would like the shutdown to happen in "10 or less seconds" from executing the command...

`shutdown now`

Seems to be a legitimate command and will shutdown your computer in less that 10 seconds, as you request.